# how to find the difference between two dataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `dataFrame`, both of them have `name` column, I want to make new `dataframe` of `dataframeA` have and `dataframeB` don't have

```
dataframeA
id     name
 1      aaa
 2      bbbb
 3      cccc
 4      gggg

dataframeB
id     name
 1      ddd
 2      aaa
 3      gggg
```

new `dataframe`

```
id     name
 1      bbbb
 2      cccc
```

Comment: Try searching SO first as common questions are mostly answered

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, ou can **merge** the two dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
merged_df = pd.merge(dataframe_a, dataframe_b, on='name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` from `functools`, or you can use `isin`, to create a `new_df` that only contains values in `dfA` that are also present in `dfB`.

**Approach 1** using `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce #import package

li = [dfA, dfB] #create list of dataframes
new_df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='name'), li) #reduce list
```

**Approach 2** using `isin`:

```
new_df = dfA[dfA['name'].isin(dfB['name])]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to utilise python's set functionality.

This will convert the specified columns to sets and then create a new dataframe using the output.

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'name': list(set(dataframeA['name'].tolist()) - set(dataframeB['name'].tolist()))
})
```